# How can I track how many mobs are alive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I've been building a Minecraft map where you fight bees (yes I know, I'm a cold-hearted person) and I'm trying to figure out a way so it stops spawning more bees when there is a certain amount (I don't want the player to get overwhelmed).

Each bee is summoned by a command block every 24 Redstone ticks (~2.4 seconds).

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the videos are dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that if I summon an armor stand on a pressure plate(heavy) every time a bee is summoned it tells me how many bees there and once a certain amount of bees are summoned I can make things happen:

Comment: I will choose another answer if it is better

Answer (score 1):

If you could simply be watching while people played this you could turn off mob spawning once a certain number of mobs spawn. However, this only works if you are not intending to publish this creation.

I’d look it up and see if there is a way to use command blocks to do this, because I am not the best at the technical side of Minecraft.

Edit: I realized my answer doesn’t make sense. If you were going to be there you could just as easily break the beehives or use a /kill command and teleport the players. You could do some calculations and figure out how long it takes, on average, for that many bees to spawn and run a command block to break the beehives after that amount of time, but this method seems very difficult. As a last resort you could change your mini game so that this isn’t a problem.

Comment: I don't use beehives I use a command block to do /summon bee

Comment: Also, beehives don't spawn bees themselves

Comment: Wdym it wouldnt work if you intend to "publish" it?

Comment: If he was to allow others to play it without him being there, the idea wouldn’t work.

Comment: If I put the world file on a public site like planet minecraft

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option would be to utilize dummy scoreboards to to keep track of the bees count (you could also make it decrease if a bee is killed) and then have a check before you spawn new bees to make sure the count is below a certain number.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard